# how can i upgrade virtio driver without updating kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Using linux kernel version 2.6.32 and corresponding virtio driver modules version. But need to upgrade all virtio drivers (virtio_net,virtio_blk,virtio_pci, virtio_ring,virtio) alone to latest version without upgrading kernel.
Is this possible, what is the dependency changes needed for kernel to compile ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You can compile the new virtio drivers with your current kernel and replace the old version of virtio under /lib/modules.

Comment: To update virtio driver there are lot of dependency files on which other kernel drivers also dependent.  If i change all those files, then i may need to change other drivers also. Is there any document for virtio driver upgrade ?

Comment: virtio driver is part of the kernel source code. If the new version can't compile with the current kernel you are using, then you might have to back port the new version(or just the new features you want to use) to the current kernel.Not sure how much work needed to get things done though.